# Maintain Nominatim with my own data

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps-api, nominatim

I just started using google map API but found some restrictions on daily request limit. After some research I found I can use open street map, but has  its own request restrictions.

To resolve I installed nominatim on my server and started using that until I found out in non metro area nominatim has very few geo points but available in google map.

I am thinking to use below approach:

1. Setup Nominatim on my server.
2. Insert OSM data to database.
3. Sync database with nightly OSM data.
4. Take the geo point from google and insert into my database.

I have below queries regarding this approach:

1. Is there any nominatim API which I can use to insert those new geo points from google in my nominatim db.
2. How will I resolve conflicts between OSM and google as I will be constantly syncing with OSM data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Google's terms of services forbid mixing their data with other sources. Likewise you are not allowed to store OSM data with proprietary data in the same database if you intend to publish this data anywhere. Read the corresponding legal terms from both Google and OSM.

Comment: As I mentioned I am not publishing that data and using only for my internal use so that shouldn't be a problem ?

Comment: "Is there any nominatim API which I can use to insert those new geo points from google in my nominatim db." - you are looking for a Google API to get these new Google addresses, right?